# Issue with npm install node-gyp and leveldown libraries

Tags: node.js, npm

During npm install I get this error first:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/patagon-clients/node_modules/leveldown
gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.9
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

After that I get another error message (after which the npm install breaks):

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! leveldown@3.0.0 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the leveldown@3.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vlado/.npm/_logs/2022-02-28T09_38_25_847Z-debug.log
```

The log in question has around 15K lines, so I will not paste it here. Do you know what might be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing some nrwl library and after that, upgraded pouchdb to version `^7.2.2` in the package.json. Didn't solve the npm install completely, but angular server now works.